# Updating the listview of second tab while changing/swipe the tab

Tags: android

I have two `Fragments` that are attached to a `FragmentActivity`.

The second fragment contains a `ListView`. I need to update the list view while changing the tab/swipe.

Comment: Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html it shows how to communicate between other fragments. You should be able to apply similar techniques for your app

Answer (score 0):

You can define your you `TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity` to implement:

```
public class TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, TabHost.OnTabChangeListener
```

and then define the following methods in your `FragmentActivity` class:

```
/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener#onTabChanged(java.lang.String)
 */
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    //TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageScrolled(int, float, int)
 */
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
        int positionOffsetPixels) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageSelected(int)
 */
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageScrollStateChanged(int)
 */
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

there you can check what fragment is being shown and update it accordingly.

Comment: public class SmartDMFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnPageChangeListener, TabHost.OnTabChangeListener{              public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
 
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub  for OnTabChangeListener() interface
  int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
  this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
  
 }